# Keeping the .dll and .pyd files in other directory

Tags: python, dll, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am using cx_Freeze to convert Python scripts to Windows executable. I am using cxfreeze script present in the Scripts directory. I want the executable generated by cxfreeze to be in a different directory and the .dll's and .pyd's in a different one. When I tried to put the two of them in separate directories the .exe did not work I got

```
The application has failed to start because python33.dll was not found. Try reinstalling to  fix this problem
```

I know this happends because the executable and (dll's & .pyd's) are located in different directories. Is there a way to keep them in different directories ?

I am using the following command to generate the executable

```
C:\Python33\Scripts>cxfreeze C:\Users\me\Desktop\setup.py --target-name=setup.exe --target-dir=C:\Users\me\Desktop\new_dir
```

Comment: [Why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What's wrong with putting the executable and DLLs in the same directory?

Comment: Anyway, on Windows, applications look for DLLs on the `%PATH%`, which includes `.`, but doesn't include, say, `../Libs/`. You can always write a .cmd wrapper around the executable that does, e.g., `PATH = %PATH%;../Libs` then `./Executable/MyApp.exe`… but usually that's not a great idea.

Comment: You modify environment variables in an initscript ([example here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/default/cx_Freeze/initscripts/ConsoleSetLibPath.py?at=default)), but I think it will still need to find at least python33.dll before it runs the initscript.

Answer (score 0):

Python for Windows really requires that the main pythonXX.dll (in this case, python33.dll) exists in C:\windows\system32\

In all of our various combinations of installing Python to different locations, network drives, etc. we've always had to use a little batch file to copy pythonXX.dll into the system32 dir.

I don't think PATH manipulation will work for you, just try copying the dll to system32 and see if your issues go away.

Then again, if you installed another version of Python to say C:\Python33 , then that windows-based installer will do this for you, and you'll be able to run your other Python location.